# freshclam problem

Tags: clamav

I  have  clamav  all installed and freshclam is working  after I do:

```
cd log
sudo mkdir clamav
sudo touch freshclam.log
sudo chown -R clamav:clamav /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

Question is : how can I make above  permanent because after some restarts  these changes go back to root and disapear ?